# How to know if phone is vibrating?

Tags: android, vibration

I wrote an app that vibrates according to a pattern:

```
vib.vibrate(..., -1);
```

I want to know when the phone finishes vibrating. Is there any way to know if it is still vibrating after I trigger that method?

thanks

Comment: By looking at the documentation it looks like there is no way to have such an information, but, by using Thread, or Handler you could be able to send a value to the UI after the time of vibration given when you call your method vibrate()

Comment: I thought the same, but I was hoping you guys could give an idea. I guess you are right! The best solution is to estimate for how long it will be vibrating based on my pattern. Thanks Jeremy D

Comment: That's the way I could do it if I had to. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can actually poll the phone to see if it's vibrating, but you could use [this](http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/vibration-examples-for-android-phone-development/) method to vibrate for a specific time period and simply keep track of this or feed it into a Handler/Timer to callback that it is finished?